# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined?

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make some sort of game on a website where it selects a random part for you. I don't know that much javascript so I don't know what that means. I took some code from here and I modified it, but this happens. It's supposed to select a random part and highlight it yellow.

```
// get all the elements from the body
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("panel");

// specify a random index
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - elems.length + 1)) + elems.length;

// get the random element
var randomElement = elems[index];

// do whatever
randomElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
```

Comment: How about `document.body.getElementsByTagName("panel");` -> `document.querySelectorAll(".panel");`? Do you want to get `<panel></panel>` tags or `<div class="panel"></div>` etc ?

Comment: <div class="panel">

Comment: the queryselectorall thing helped!! can you post it as an answer so I can accept it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Issue

❌This gets `<panel>` tags.

```
var elems = document.body.getElementsByTagName("panel");
```

✅Change to this. It gets `<anyElement class="panel">` like `<div class="panel">`

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll(".panel");
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with getting the random index. You are trying to generate a random number from 0 to elems.length but this code `Math.floor(Math.random() * (0 - elems.length + 1)) + elems.length;` is adding `elems.length` to the random generated number thus your `index` is going more than the `elems` elements array length. You need to generate an index with maximum of `elems.length-1`. If you will console your `index` then you will see the problem.

Given that the html element is

```
<div class="panel">
```

Try this:

```
// get all the elements from the body
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("panel");

// specify a random index
var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * elems.length);
```

Also check the docs for `Math.random()` in here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: No need to call `Math.floor()` on `elems.length`

Comment: Check the usage of Math.random() in here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random

Comment: I know what `Math.random()` returns, what I am saying is `Math.floor(elems.length)` is useless, as `length` is always an integer

Comment: Yeah you are correct. Let me update it @MemeComposer no that comment was for the author

Answer (score 0):

Check, whether the element exist before setting style to it.

```
 If(randomElement) {
     randomElement.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
    }
```